# lowercase only letters between brackets

Tags: php, uppercase, brackets

i am trying to Convert everything between brackets to lowercase letters.

```
$text = 'AABBCC [AA] AAbbCC [Bb] aabbcc [cc]';
preg_match_all('/\([^)]+\)/', $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) 
{
    $match = strtolower($match);
    $text = preg_replace(strtolower($match), $match, $text);
}
echo $text;
```

the output

```
'AABBCC [AA] AAbbCC [Bb] aabbcc [cc]'
```

the output i need is

```
'AABBCC [aa] AAbbCC [bb] aabbcc [cc]'
```

Comment: Your regex is looking for `(` and `)`, but your input text has `[` and `]` characters. Can you explain this?

Comment: I'm still learning programming and it is normal that there will be many mistakes .. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts I found a solution...
I was hoping to use **preg_replace** instead of **str_replace** but I'll try again

```
$text = 'AABBCC [AA] AAbbCC [Bb] aabbcc [cc]';

preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $text, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) 
{ 
    $text = str_replace("$match", strtolower("$match"), "$text");
}
echo $text;
```

the output

```
AABBCC [aa] AAbbCC [bb] aabbcc [cc]
```